Troubleshooting Nuxt route conflict with Laravel API on Digital Ocean"
I have an application hosted on Digital Ocean, which is composed of a front-end (FE) and a back-end (BE) component. The front-end is a Nuxt application with an HTTP route at "/", while the back-end is a Laravel application with an HTTP route at "/api". However, I'm unable to access the "/api" route because Nuxt interprets it as a landing page.
Where should I start troubleshooting this issue? Could it be related to the Nuxt configuration or is it something specific to Digital Ocean? I've attempted to find solutions online but to no avail, or perhaps I'm not using the right search terms. I've thought about ignoring a specific route in Nuxt, but I don't think that's possible. Additionally, I haven't found any settings in Digital Ocean that seem to be related to this behavior.

You can setup a proxy for your application. Try this https://traefik.io/traefik/
